# Freeing memory of structure linked list using expiration of function scope

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, scope

My goal is to run a API call repeatedly and check for memory leaks.
The API takes in integer input and returns a pointer to the first structure in a linked list of structures as output. Each structure may have struct variables of other types. 
In the following code i have tried to represent my problem.

The problem is in callApi() function. I need to dispose of the memory occupied by the structure 'output' that the API() returns. Even if i use free(output) here, it will cause a memory leak because since it points to a linked list of nested structures.  (source of info : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Memory_management)

Question:
When leaving exiting callApi() call, will the 'output' nested structure expire when control goes out of the function back to main()? Will it free the entire memory occupied? 
 Please suggest a solution to way to solve this memory leak problem.

`Can this problem be overcome with C++?`

```
typedef struct{
  int dev_size;
  char *dev_name;
  dev_stat *next_dev;
  mem_stat *mem_info;
} dev_stat

typedef struct{
  int mem_capacity;
  char *mem_name;
} mem_stat

int main()
{
  int input;
  int return_val;
  int callApi(int);
  while(1)
  {
     return_val=callApi(input);
     print return_val;
  }
}

int callApi(int ip)
{
  //Update: Memory allocation is unnecessary as it is done inside the API() call itself
  //dev_stat *output=(dev_stat *)calloc(2,sizeof(dev_stat));
  int ret_val;
  ret_val=API(ip,&output);
  free(output);
  output=NULL;
  return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: what is 'int callApi(int);' doing in your main ?

Comment: the program is just for giving the general idea of program flow. it is not exact to C syntax. Reason for using callApi() : If i call API() within main() the variables used will never go out of scope until the program ends. So calling API() within callApi() which is inturn called from within a infinite loop in main()

Comment: Can the problem be overcome with C++?

Comment: @kk: with C++ you might have `dev_name` a `std::string`, `next_dev` and `mem_info` smart pointers, so your structure would release all the memory properly when deallocated. But as long as your API doesn't provide C++-style structures as its output, you're stuck with C-style manual deallocation.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is, no, the memory will not "expire" when you exit a function.

The API *should* provide a way to "free" the returned value, if it is a complex structure. If it doesn't, then traversing the structure yourself and freeing it is probably the only way out.

Answer (score 3):

The first question who is the *owner* of the structures you are going to free.

It might be that the API returns a pointer to its internal structure, which you must not deallocate (because, for example, it may be shared).

It might be as well that your code is responsible for deallocating the structure itself, but not the other structures that your structure points to. This way you need to just free the returned structure and forget about it.

It might be however that your responsibility is to free the whole object tree starting at the returned structure. In that case it's to be expected that the API has some function which properly deallocates the structure with its descendants for you. If not (which is most likely not the case), you have to free all the resources referenced by your structure, recursively.

You should look up at the APi documentation to find out  which if the three cases is your case.

---

Update:
Explicitly for your case (the whole structure should be deallocated manually), I would use something like that:

```
void free_mem_stat(struct mem_stat* p)
{
    if (!p) return;
    free(p->mem_name);
    free(p);
}

void free_dev_stat(struct dev_stat* p)
{
    // first, clean up the leaves
    for(struct dev_stat* curr = p; curr; curr = curr->next_dev)
    {
        free(curr->dev_name);
        free_mem_stat(curr->mem_info);
    }
    // than, clean up the linked list
    for(struct dev_stat* curr = p; curr; /**/)
    {
        struct dev_stat* next = curr->next_dev;
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
}

int callApi(int ip)
{
    int ret_val;
    struct dev_stat* output;
    ret_val = API(ip, &output);
    free_dev_stat(output);
    return ret_val;
}
```

Note that the function like `free_dev_stat` ought to be provided by the API itself, if the API developers really intend to let the users deallocate their structures.

Comment: the structure is the output from the API. so the API will not be deallocating it. I guess the only option is recursively free the structure.

Comment: @kk: in your case, who is allocating `next_dev`? Strange is that you must allocate the first structure yourself, but not the next ones.

Comment: allocation for next_dev is done within the third party API call API().

Comment: i think there is no need for me to allocate memory for the first structure. I updating the code to remove the calloc allocation.

Comment: @kk: added example of a deallocator